# Please help me identify set

Tags: part-identification

Please help me identify which sets these are from. I got a bag or LEGO and I think it is from multiple sets.

[image: lego]

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The white [Plate 1X2 W. Vertical Schaft](http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4611700) is probably from [4625: Pink Brick Box](http://brickset.com/sets/4625-1/Pink-Brick-Box) from your other [question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7181/please-help-me-identify-set-thanks/7185#7185)

The [Turbine Ø31.81 X 2](http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4296548) and [Tail Ø 3,2](http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4294148) are only together in [7984-1: Deep Sea Raider](http://brickset.com/sets/7984-1/Deep-Sea-Raider)

The combination of the white [Mini Claw W. Fork](http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4211726) and the black [Link 1M Fric/Fork/Stumpf](http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4507820) can only be found together in some of the 2015 Deep Sea sets.

Answer (score 0):

They can easily be from earlier sets like the aqua themes, or it can be from the Lego batman Batcave from 2012.